# Does `top_n()` work for <Date> data class types?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
set.seed(1)
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(col1 = c(rep("a", 4), c(rep("b", 4))),
             col2 = as.Date(c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", 
                              "2019-04-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", 
                              "2019-03-01", "2019-04-01")),
             col3 = runif(8))
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#>   col1  col2        col3
#>   <chr> <date>     <dbl>
#> 1 a     2019-01-01 0.266
#> 2 a     2019-02-01 0.372
#> 3 a     2019-03-01 0.573
#> 4 a     2019-04-01 0.908
#> 5 b     2019-01-01 0.202
#> 6 b     2019-02-01 0.898
#> 7 b     2019-03-01 0.945
#> 8 b     2019-04-01 0.661
```

I want to filter out the newest month from each group in the data frame above (filter out 2019-04-01). I thought the `dplyr` code below would do the trick. But `dplyr::top_n()` doesn't appear to be working on my `col2`. Is it because `col2` is 'date' class? What's with the strange warning? And finally, once I get some type of working code can I use `dplyr::top_n(-1, col2)` instead of `dplyr::top_n(3, col2)` to get rid of the largest value?

```
df %>% group_by(col1) %>% top_n(col2, 3)
#> # A tibble: 8 x 3
#> # Groups:   col1 [2]
#>   col1  col2         col3
#>   <chr> <date>      <dbl>
#> 1 a     2019-01-01 0.629 
#> 2 a     2019-02-01 0.0618
#> 3 a     2019-03-01 0.206 
#> 4 a     2019-04-01 0.177 
#> 5 b     2019-01-01 0.687 
#> 6 b     2019-02-01 0.384 
#> 7 b     2019-03-01 0.770 
#> 8 b     2019-04-01 0.498 
#> Warning messages:
#> 1: In if (n > 0) { :
#>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
#> 2: In if (n > 0) { :
#>   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: You're using the arguments in the wrong order. Either correct the order with `top_n(3, col2)` or name the arguments, `top_n(wt = col2, n = 3)`. A negative `n` will select from the bottom, see `?top_n` for details.

Comment: ...So you could do `top_n(-(n() - 1), wt)`. But I'd probably do `... %>% arrange(col2) %>% slice(-1)` instead. For `slice`, negative indices remove. Seems clearer.

Comment: @Gregor thanks, and why does `top_n(iris, 5, Sepal.Width)` return six results, when it's only "top 5"? Strange.

Comment: Again, I'll point you to the help page `?top_n`. *"Note that we get more
 than 2 values here because there's a tie: `top_n()` either takes
 all rows with a value, or none."*

Comment: @Gregor Sorry, when I looked I didn't notice two values of `3.9`. Thought they were six unique values. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gregor I simply had the orders reversed.

```
df %>% group_by(col1) %>% top_n(col2, 3)  # wrong order
```

should have been:

```
df %>% group_by(col1) %>% top_n(3, col2)  # right order
```

or I could've been thorough and named the arguments:

```
df %>% group_by(col1) %>% top_n(wt = col2, n = 3)
```